# fixing a column position in angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm trying to fix the position of a `div` in angularjs (1.5) using a library called macgyver (https://angular-macgyver.github.io/MacGyver/0.3.10/index.html). The div `id="reportOption"` stays in the fixed position while div `id="reports"` scrolls down. But what happens is that div `id="reports"` ends up shifting left on the page when scrolling and overlaps div `id="reportOption"`...any idea on why this could be happening?

```
<div class="row">
    <h1 align="center">Reports</h1>

</div>
<div class="row ">
        <div id="reportOption" class="col-md-2" style="border:1pt solid black" mac-affix >
            <br><br><br><br>this should be fixed
        </div>

        <div id="reports" class="col-md-10">
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
                      <br>1
        </div>
</div>
```

I tried to make a plunker to show this but couldn't get the plunker to work...https://plnkr.co/edit/7Sw9P1iZ6cqNLSURPqC5?p=preview

I'm also open to other ways of doing this too...

Comment: Looking at this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you want, but to fix a div, you can always add: `position: fixed;` to style.